# How much precipitation must fall within a catchment area to fill up a sink’s entire volume assuming that the runoff conditions are perfect

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, hydrology

I am performing an exercise and I need to answer these question, any hints would be extremely useful.

**How can it be calculated how much precipitation that must fall within a catchment area to fill up a sink’s entire volume assuming that the runoff conditions are perfect (i.e. the entire runoff from the precipitation reaches a local sink)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with perfect run off and if time is not taken into account (instantaneous run off), your sink will be filled when the area of the catchment multiplied by the height of the precipitation is equal to its volume (assuming that there is no run off FROM the sink). So you want the volume of the sink divided by its catchment area.

see [watershed](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000059000000) if you need to find the catchment area. I won't tell more otherwise this is no more exercise ;-)